# jQuery .css property not working on scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning jQuery by implementing its properties. I am having difficulties when I'm trying to make a div stick to the top of the page when its scrolled to. This is my HTML div:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_2 poll_div" id="poll-div">
                    <p>POLL OF THE WEEK</p>
                    <p>Best pakistani singer?</p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%">
                                <input type="submit" id="op1" onclick="load(this.id);" class="options option1" value="option # 1"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="numb">
                                <div id="votes1"><?php $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
                                                        mysql_select_db('poll');
                                                        $row= mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `polls` WHERE 1"));
                                                        echo $row['option1'] . "/" . $row['total'] ?></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%">
                                <input type="submit" id="op2" onclick="load(this.id);" class="options option2" value="option # 1"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="numb">
                                <div id="votes2"><?php echo $row['option2'] . "/" . $row['total'] ?></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%">
                                <input type="submit" id="op3" onclick="load(this.id);" class="options option3" value="option # 1"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="numb">
                                <div id="votes3"><?php echo $row['option3'] . "/" . $row['total'] ?></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div> <!--Poll-->
```

**EDIT**
CSS:

```
background-color: white;
position: fixed;
width: 25%;
float: right;
margin-right: 2%;
margin-top: 3.5%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

and finally JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 280 && $("#poll_div").css('position') == 'relative'){
            $("#poll_div").css("position", "fixed");
        }

        if($(this).scrollTop() < 400 && $("#poll_div").css('position') == 'fixed'){
            $("#poll_div").css({'position': 'static'});
        }
    });
});
```

If I place the line `window.alert("Hello");` instead of the css property change in JQuery, it works fine but not this css property line.

Comment: You want it to be fixed between 280 and 400 pixels ??

Comment: you should just add a class and remove it when you reach those positions then it will be easier.  Otherwise you want to change the position back to relative rather than static, otherwise your fixed positioning will only work on first scroll

Comment: @Mateutek Yes exactly

Comment: I have added a "DEMO" with your code. Please verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add Position fixed**

You can add `position:fixed;` in you style and accomplish your need

```
.poll_div{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;//removed position relative
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 30px;    
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/sLx3n2vz/4/)

[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/sLx3n2vz/7/)

Comment: I tried it but it remains sticked to  the right corner and when I scroll down it scrolls with it like a fixed navbar

Comment: @AhmedDhanani I have added a "DEMO" with your code. Is that fine? verify.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. I checked your demo, but that does not works fine at my end. I have edited the question with the edited css.

Comment: Actually that worked. It was a little bit of problem with some other div. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 280 && $("#poll-div").css('position') == 'relative'){
        $("#poll-div").css("position", "fixed");
    }

    if($(this).scrollTop() < 400 && $("#poll-div").css('position') == 'fixed'){
        $("#poll-div").css({'position': 'static'});
    }
});
});
```

Check your id in html

```
<div class="col span_1_of_2 poll_div" id="poll-div">
```

You can simplify it to this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 280 && $(this).scrollTop() < 400){
        $("#poll-div").css("position", "fixed");
    }else{
       $("#poll-div").css("position", "static");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems a nice solution. But actually the problem was with its position in the css :)